# Link to Reporting Services reports in ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have an ASP.NET app and want to link to reports that run in Reporting Services and allow the user to view the reports.  I am unclear about how to do this.  Is there some example that shows how this is done and what html I use to link to the reports?  The mrt files are created but I don't know what the next steps are to have them render to the user via the ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Microsoft Report Viewer control inside Reporting category in toolbox, I use this and works fine with linking SSRS reports

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this.  One of which is to use the SSRS [Report Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251692%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) another way is to use an IFRAME and point to the report - which is the way the [Telerik Silverlight HTML placeholder](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/htmlplaceholder.aspx) works.